# How to chunk a stream and keep it going

Tags: java, java-stream

How can I split a stream of objects into smaller chunks, so instead of objects passing through 1-by-1, they pass in lists of size N:

Just to explain what I intend, but probably different:

```
objectStream
   .map(do something here)
   .peek(list -> each list of size N or the last one shorter than N)
   ....
```

Comment: Why don't you do this at the source? Say your source is `List<E>`, can you partition it as `List<List<E>>` and proceed?

Comment: We are reading a stream of data from database, and we don't want to materialize all of it before filtering it later. But before filtering it we need to chunk every N elements to call an external service.

Comment: You can't do this with streams directly.  You can do it with `Stream.iterator()`, though.

Comment: Rather than ask how to implement your proposed solution, better to describe your problem and ask for suggested solutions. Have you considered using [parallel streams](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+parallel+stream) ?

Comment: If streams are not sufficient for your needs, consider using loops.

Comment: https://openjdk.org/jeps/461

Answer (score 1):

This isn't much help to you now, but a future JDK might allow you to do this with stream gatherer, see [JEP461](https://openjdk.org/jeps/461).

The examples provided in JEP461 shows different ways to alter elements of the stream for downstream processing, handling intermediate operations on multiple elements or changing the stream element type.

This shows how to group elements into a window size of 2/3/4 elements, and runs in latest [JDK22](https://jdk.java.net/22/) with `--enable-preview` mode:

```
Stream.of(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).gather(fixedWindow(2)).forEach(System.out::println);
=>
[0, 1]
[2, 3]
[4, 5]
[6, 7]
[8, 9]

Stream.of(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).gather(fixedWindow(3)).forEach(System.out::println);
=>
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
[6, 7, 8]
[9]

Stream.of(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9).gather(fixedWindow(4)).forEach(System.out::println);
=>
[0, 1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
[8, 9]
```

This works with a predefined `fixedWindow` gatherer defined in `java.util.stream.Gatherer` interface, or use/adapt an inlined definition (copied from JEP461):

```
static <TR> Gatherer<TR, ?, List<TR>> fixedWindow(int windowSize) {

    // Validate input
    if (windowSize < 1)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("window size must be non-zero");

    // This gatherer is inherently order-dependent,
    // so it should not be parallelized
    return Gatherer.ofSequential(

            // The initializer creates an ArrayList which holds the current
            // open window
            () -> new ArrayList<TR>(windowSize),

            // The integrator is invoked for each element consumed
            Gatherer.Integrator.ofGreedy((window, element, downstream) -> {

                // Add the element to the current open window
                window.add(element);

                // Until we reach our desired window size,
                // return true to signal that more elements are desired
                if (window.size() < windowSize)
                    return true;

                // When window is full, close it by creating a copy
                var result = new ArrayList<TR>(window);

                // Clear the window so the next can be started
                window.clear();

                // Send the closed window downstream
                return downstream.push(result);

            }),

            // The combiner is omitted since this operation is intrinsically sequential,
            // and thus cannot be parallelized

            // The finisher runs when there are no more elements to pass from the upstream
            (window, downstream) -> {
                // If the downstream still accepts more elements and the current
                // open window is non-empty then send a copy of it downstream
                if(!downstream.isRejecting() && !window.isEmpty()) {
                    downstream.push(new ArrayList<TR>(window));
                    window.clear();
                }
            }

    );
}
```

Comment: I don’t see the point of copying the source code of the gatherer. It doesn’t help for previous Java versions, as they don’t have gatherers and it’s not necessary for the new version either, as programmers can simply use the method without caring for its internal details.